# Function on HP Prime calculator to get Symbolic expression of Fourier transform from Laplace transformation

Tags: laplace-transform, fourier-transform, calculator

I would like to have a simple algorithm (or function) on HP Prime calculator to get symbolic expression of the Fourier transform of a function.

On my HP Prime, it is possible to get the Laplace transformation (analytical expression) of a function.

From this post :

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28100/relation-between-laplace-and-fourier-transforms

It seems that a relation between the 2 transformations is possible (HP prime calculator can also calculate limits on symbolic expression).

Has anyone already try to do this ? Any help or feedback is welcome

ps : I don't know if it is possible to implement this automatic calculation through a HP-Prime native language ? Indeed, I have just received it, I don't know all its functionalities.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply replace into the analytical expression of Laplace transformed function the $s$ variable by $s=j\omega$.

Comment: ok but this replacement has not has not constraints to do this rep twilleck